# Bonnet (hood) release cable broken on Saab 93

Tags: hood

I have a Saab 93, 1999 vintage. I went to open the bonnet (hood) and the release cable snapped.

What's the easiest way to release the bonnet without the release cable? I need to open it to top up fluids and also to repar the cable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know where it snapped?

When this happened on my 900, I was able to get at the release cable from under the car - but it took some stretching, and a long pair of pliers.  (It broke right at the catch.)

Comment: No, I don't know where it broke (yet).